# How to convert a single band to multi-band raster?

Tags: qgis, raster

I have paletted or unique values but they are not different bands. Now, I want to convert this band 1 (Pallette) to different bands based on the value (0-17). Can anyone help me in this regard?
[image]

Comment: You can do this with GDAL_Translate -expand RGB option https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html the QGIS Raster::Translate is a dialog for this command line, if the -expand isn't in the list you should be able to edit the command to include the option.

Comment: I tried GDAL_Translate(convert) but did not find a way to convert different values to bands

Comment: The option isn't there on the GUI, you will have to edit the command line or run the utility from command line.

Comment: Unlike in other options, GDAL-Translate is not allowing me to edit the command line.

Comment: Hey Michael, I am able to edit the command line now. This is how it looks: gdal_translate -expand rgb C:/BackUp/LandUse_AP-20181116T163825Z-001/LandUse_AP/lulc250k_0506_14871.tif

Comment: I have converted my original palleted raster to RGB raster. Now, I can see three bands: Red, Green and Blue. Thanks

Comment: That's great, can you please answer your own question with screen shots for the benefit of future users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else finds this question, the answer is in the comments above. Here are screenshots from QGIS 3.10 to help:

1. Search for "Translate" in the Processing Toolbox menu. You want `GDAL > Translate (convert format)`

[image]

2. In the dialogue box that appears, expand the "Advanced parameters". In the "Additional command-line parameters" box, type `-expand rgb`. Then click OK.

[image]